# Chunk output into files, based on number of entries and total size

Tags: go, stream

Below is my client code which stream all the customer URLs from a golang grpc server. It takes `Request` input parameter and streams customer URLs based on matching a particular `clientId`.  In my this code, I am streaming all customer URLs for ClientId 12345 and it works fine.

I am also creating an XML file with all the URLs in it for particular `clientId` as shown below. I need to split an XML file into multiple XML files for same `clientId` to ensure it conforms to these requirements:

- A single XML file should not be more than **50MB** max. It can be approximate, doesn't have to be accurate.
- A single XML file should not have more than **50K** URLs max.

I know it's weird that 50k URL limit will be reached sooner than 50MB limit but this is the requirement I have. Based on above logic, I need to make multiple XML files for particular `clientId`. All those multiple files can be like `12345_abc_1.xml`, `12345_abc_2.xml` or any other better naming format.

Below is the code I got which works fine but I am opting for code review to see if anything can be improved or optimized so that it can be run efficiently.

```
func main() {
    // this "clientId" will be configurable in future
    clientId := 12345
    timeout := time.Duration(1000) * time.Millisecond
    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), timeout)
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "localhost:50005", grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("can not connect with server %v", err)
    }

    // create stream
    client := pb.NewCustomerServiceClient(conn)
    req := &pb.Request{ClientId: clientId}
    stream, err := client.FetchResponse(context.Background(), req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("open stream error %v", err)
    }
    // create new object to populate all URL data in memory
    urlHolder := NewClient()
    t := time.Unix(0, 0).UTC()
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        // create new object to populate all URL data in memory
        urlHolder := NewClient()
        urlCounter := 0
        byteCounter := 0
        fileCounter := 0

        for {
            resp, err := stream.Recv()
            if err == io.EOF {
                done <- true
                file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%d_abc_%d.xml", clientId, fileCounter))
                urlHolder.WriteTo(file)
                return
            }
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("can not receive %v", err)
            }
            log.Printf("Resp received: %s", resp.GetCustomerUrl())
            // I add the bytes of the URL here as a return
            urlBytes := urlHolder.Add(&URL{
                Loc:        resp.GetCustomerUrl(),
                LastMod:    &t,
                ChangeFreq: Daily,
                Priority:   10.2,
            })
            byteCounter += urlBytes
            urlCounter += 1
            if byteCounter > 49000000 || urlCounter >= 50000 {
                file, _ := os.Create(fmt.Sprintf("%d_abc_%d.xml", clientId, fileCounter))
                urlHolder.WriteTo(file)
                urlHolder = NewClient() // create a new object for next loop
                fileCounter += 1        // prepare fileCounter for next loop
                byteCounter = 0         // restart count variables
                urlCounter = 0
            }
        }
    }()

    <-done
    log.Printf("finished")
}
```

Here is my `urlholder.go` file:

```
type URL struct {
    Loc        string     `xml:"loc"`
    LastMod    *time.Time `xml:"lastmod"`
    ChangeFreq ChangeFreq `xml:"changefreq"`
    Priority   float32    `xml:"priority"`
}

type UrlMap struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
    Xmlns   string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    URLs    []*URL   `xml:"url"`
    Minify  bool     `xml:"-"`
}

func NewClient() *UrlMap {
    return &UrlMap{
        Xmlns: "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9",
        URLs:  make([]*URL, 0),
    }
}

func (s *UrlMap) Add(u *URL) (int) {
    s.URLs = append(s.URLs, u)
    var urlBytes []byte
    var err error

    urlBytes, err = xml.Marshal(u) // Transform to bytes using xml.Marshal or xml.MarshalIndent
    if err != nil {
        panic(err) // or return the error
    }
    return len(urlBytes)
}

// WriteTo writes XML encoded urlMap to given io.Writer.
func (s *UrlMap) WriteTo(w io.Writer) (n int64, err error) {
    cw := NewCounterWriter(w)
    _, err = cw.Write([]byte(xml.Header))
    if err != nil {
      return cw.Count(), err
    }
    en := xml.NewEncoder(cw)
    if !s.Minify {
      en.Indent("", "  ")
    }
    err = en.Encode(s)
    cw.Write([]byte{'\n'})
    return cw.Count(), err
}
```

Here is my `CounterWriter` class -

```
type CounterWriter struct {
    writer io.Writer
    count  int64
}

var _ io.Writer = (*CounterWriter)(nil)

func NewCounterWriter(w io.Writer) (cw *CounterWriter) {
    return &CounterWriter{
        writer: w,
    }
}

func (cw *CounterWriter) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = cw.writer.Write(p)
    cw.count = cw.count + int64(n)
    return n, err
}

// Count returns the number of bytes written to the Writer.
func (cw *CounterWriter) Count() (n int64) {
    return cw.count
}
```

**Problem Statement**

I am looking for code review on above code:

- Is there anything that can be improved in terms of multiple XML file generation logic? I modified my `Add` method in `urlholder.go` file to return bytes (which is `int`) but I also have `WriteTo` method in same go file which also returns bytes (which is `int64`). Can we simplify my above multiple `XML` file generation logic?
- Also do we need to use interface to split out above class and make it more clean?

I am just trying to learn on how to write good go code as this code will be running in production.

Comment: I changed the title. Please check that I haven't misrepresented your code, and correct it if I have.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thank you Toby. Appreciate the edit. Looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very clear and readable in general. I came up with a very nitpicky list of style suggestions :)

### A few comments on `main()`

- `time.Duration(1000) * time.Millisecond` can be written as just `1000 * time.Millisecond`
- Call the cancel function from `context.WithTimeout`, otherwise your program has a resource leak (not that it matters from main, but still).

  ```
  ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(...)
  defer cancel()
  ```
- Use `ctx` consistently, there are some places in `main` where it refers to `context.Background()` instead.
- Handle the error from `os.Create`, or your code will be impossible to debug when it fails.
- Similarly, you probably want to print an error if `urlHolder.WriteTo` fails.
- I would also suggest making a helper function for creating the XML file and writing to it, in particular if you ever change the file naming pattern you would need to change it in two places.
- I think there's no need for a goroutine in main? You can just run it directly unless I'm missing something.

### A few things on `urlholder.go`

- Time `time.Time` type is almost always used as a value and not as a pointer. The `URL.LastMod` field should be a `time.Time`, not a `*time.Time`.
- This is subjective, but `UrlMap` should be spelled as `URLMap`.
- No need to `make` a slice of size zero, just use `nil`.
- `UrlMap.Add` should return an error instead of panicing.
- The `UrlMap.Add` method uses a different method of serialization than `WriteTo`, so the byte count may not be correct. I would suggest calling `WriteTo` from inside `Add`, as follows

  ```
  func (m *UrlMap) Add(u *URL) int {
      s.URLs = append(s.URLs, u)
      var out strings.Builder
      m.WriteTo(&out)
      return len(out.String())
  }
  ```

I'm not sure what the point of `CounterWriter` is when the result of `urlHolder.WriteTo` is ignored anyway.

And since you asked about interfaces, there's no need to use an interface here. In general you should only refactor to use interfaces when you already have two implementations in mind. Using an interface preemptively for a "cleaner" design is an example of YAGNI: you ain't gonna need it.

Comment: Thanks for good suggestion. Can you provide an example for this point `making a helper function for creating the XML file`? Just confuse on how will I separate it out? or you mean to say just move `os.Create` line into a separate function? Also you mentioned `no need for a goroutine in main` point - I am kinda confuse on what does this mean. If you can provide an example basis on my suggestion then it will help me great.

Comment: Also most importantly confusion I had earlier was I am returning bytes from `Add` method and also returning bytes from `WriteTo` method too. So I was thinking do I really need to return bytes from `Add` method to deal with multiple XML file generation or I can also use `WriteTo` method too? I mean what does make sense most for my use case?

Comment: I meant that `os.Create` and `urlHolder.WriteTo` should together go in a helper function, but it's pretty subjective. Or just moving the file name pattern to a shared global variable would also reduce the risk of forgetting to change it in two places.

Comment: Your `main()` launches a goroutine and waits on it with `<-done`, I think all the code inside the `go func() {...}` can just be written directly in the top-level `main` function.

Comment: Ah, it took me some time to understand your confusion about the `Add` vs `WriteTo` methods but you're right they should be unified. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. My `WriteTo` method responsibility is to write XML file on the disk. I know that method isn't doing exactly what it should do as there is some bug but in your new suggestion if we use `WriteTo` method from `Add` and since `WriteTo` will write XML file, how will that work?

Comment: My suggestion is using the fact that `WriteTo` accepts an `io.Writer`. If you pass an open file to `WriteTo`, it will write to the file. If you pass a `strings.Builder` to `WriteTo`, it will instead serialize the result into a string rather than writing to a file.

Comment: Yup understood now and it makes sense to me. Sorry for late reply. I think this looks good. I just have one last question. Let's say if I want to expose `WriteToS3` method as well in same `urlholder.go` file then is there any way to get `byte[]` that I can use  to write all the contents in an S3 file in a bucket? The purpose of that new method is to create a new S3 file in a bucket on aws. I am just confuse on how does my `WriteToS3` method will look like. I already have a way to write on aws in a s3 file. Just confuse on how to get byte[] of data that I need to write into.

Comment: If you do `var buf bytes.Buffer; urlHolder.WriteTo(&buf)` then you can use `buf.Bytes()` for the content of the XML as bytes. Let me know if I misunderstood what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is where I am confuse. I created a play [here](https://play.golang.com/p/MvqLljPVnNb). I added new `WriteToS3` method but I am not sure what should be inside so that I can write the bytes to S3. This is a new method I want to expose which can write XML file into S3. Where should I add this `var buf bytes.Buffer;`?

Comment: or you mean to say call this first `urlHolder.WriteTo(&buf)` which will give me the bytes and then call `WriteToS3` method again to write data into S3? If yes then anything can be improved here?

Comment: I was suggesting to call `WriteTo` from within `WriteToS3`.

Comment: You mean this [way](https://play.golang.com/p/FKXjlrCE0GL)? And then call this `WriteToS3` method directly from main.go to write into s3 correct? If I am doing wrong, can you provide an example please? It will help me clear my doubt.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134627/discussion-between-andyp-and-rose).